# an error (403) forbidden is being thrown on execution of web-service

Tags: web-services

I have a middle-ware application where only web services are deployed.

Another application calling one of my services is getting "the remote server returned an error (403) forbidden" error.

My services are up and running fine. 
please tell me which end is responsible for this error and what could be the possible reasons for this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't have permission to use one of those web services but you need to test that on your own.

Comment: the application has been using the service.so, I don't think there's any permission related issue. and if you still think that there can be permission related issue, please explain that

Comment: the only reason where I have ever seen a 403 is when there is a problem with the code that it could be easily hacked or change by users so there could be something with your code/program you use to run your code. i have also got an 403 when i didn't log into a page and went to that URL where you are normaly not allowed. or your api needs an api key

Comment: so basically, it's a problem on the service's caller end not on the middle-ware application's. am I right?

Comment: i do think so but not 100% sure